# For increasing shower pressure, Mixer or thermostatic valve?

Tags: plumbing, shower, boiler

I all, I'm looking to purchase a new shower for my combi boiler and am looking to maximise water pressure output.

I'd like to know what one produces better water pressure? Mixer based or TRV controlled showers?

And are there any after market products that can boost the water pressure for a combi boiler system? Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those should have a noticeable impact on water pressure, that's up to your bladder tank, or the line pressure from the utility.

You may consider using a more efficient showerhead, which typically *reduce* flow, but *increase* pressure. Unless you're trying to fill buckets in your shower, this will probably be your best bet.